# Django: Remove duplicate data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I am using Django and React for my app. I am really new in Django rest frame work. I have made three models, they are `order`, `customer`  and `products`. `Order` models have many to one relationship with customers and products. I fetched the data successfully to  React frontend. But the problem is when I make new entries, for example: when user order new product. It give each time same user's name is frontend [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HKV2.png). I checked some documentation and stackover-flow questions but did not find the right answers. I know i need do something in my `views.py's` Order query but don't know how.

**This is my models**

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null= True)
    email =  models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    date_created= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Tag(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    CATEGORY=(
         ('Indoor', 'Indoor'),
         ('Outdoor', 'Outdoor'),

            )

    name= models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    price= models.FloatField(null=True)
    category=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True, choices=CATEGORY)
    description= models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True, blank= True)
    date_created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    tags= models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Order(models.Model):
    STATUS =(
         ('Pending', 'Pending'),
         ('Out of delivery', 'Out of delivery'),
         ('Delivered', 'Delivered'),
    )
    status= models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True,choices= STATUS)
    date_created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null= True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL, related_name='orders')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null= True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL, related_name='orders')
```

**This is my views.py**

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def orderList(request):
    orders = Order.objects.all()
    serializer = OrderSerializer(orders, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['POST'])
def orderCreate(request):
    serializer = OrderSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['GET'])
def customerList(request):
    customers = Customer.objects.values_list('name', flat=True).distinct()
    serializer = CustomerSerializer(customers, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)


@api_view(['GET'])
def customerDetail(request, pk):
    customers = Customer.objects.get(id=pk)
    # orders = customers.order_set.all()
    serializer = CustomerWithProductsSerializer(customers, many=False)

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

**This is my serializer**

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    customer = CustomerSerializer()
    product = ProductSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['status', 'customer', 'product']
```

Comment: Maybe something like this `customer=set(Customer.objects.values_list('name', flat=True))` rather `distinct()`

Comment: Where should i add this code?`

Comment: Because I am getting data from `Order`. Should not be something with Order views or Serializers?